# How to add a value to existing value of sql table in yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have created a stock module in yii2. Using gii functionality  I can add products to table. But what to do when product already exists in the table and new quantity needs to be added to existing quantity leaving total quantity in db. For example,

Products

> Quantity
>
> > 5

I need to update Quantity by any value for example '5+3', leaving other fields of sql table unchanged.

need output like below

> Quantity
>
> > 8

How do I update my controller to do that? And of course I want to be able to do it in create action.

Comment: I am very new to yii2 or any kind of framework, so I don't actually know what should I do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps you should follow:

1. Figure out how you identify if a product already exists. Based on what? name? internal code? etc.
2. When you create a product search the db to see if that product already exists based on your criteria.
3. Decide what you do with the extra data, what if the product is already there based on the code but the name has changed.
4. If it does exist then update the quantity.

Comment: Well, I understood the working procedure on what I needed to do by my own. Mainly I was looking for YII2  default code for update by specific value. Anyway I did it using query builder.

Comment: Do not do that, use the ActiveRecord. There are many advantages using ActiveQuery, like being able to install audit extensions, automatic update_time and update_by insertion etc. the Yii2 code you are looking for is in the actionUpdate() function, but you need to combine it with create too.